# Asp.net MessageBox doesn't exist in context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a connection class in asp.net to save values in list i have written following code but it is generating error that `MessageBox` doesn't exist. I google this and have found 
few answers but these are also not working here my code is:

```
 public static class Connection
    {
        public static ArrayList GetCoffeeByType(string coffeetype)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();
                var query = from p in db.tableabc select p;
                list = query.ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());

            }
            return list;
        }
}
```

I tried this `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('" + Message + "')", true);` -- But it is also showing error at `this` and `Message` -- how can i show this MessageBox?

Comment: MessageBox is something available on WInforms , You should use javascript alert() to show a error message to the client , Please try using a Callback

Comment: You don't have to use messagebox in web , use javascript alert instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a static class called Alert with one public method called Show. The implementation is as simple as can be. Just put the .cs file in the App_Code folder on your website and you instantly have access to the method from all pages and user controls.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;

/// <summary>
/// A JavaScript alert
/// </summary>
publicstaticclass Alert
{

/// <summary>
/// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param>
publicstaticvoid Show(string message)
{
   // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
   string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
   string script ="<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('"+ cleanMessage +"');</script>";

   // Gets the executing web page
   Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

   // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
   if (page !=null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
   {
      page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
   }
}    
}
```

**Demonstration**

That class enables you to add a JavaScript alert to any page at any time. Here is an example of a `Button.Click` event handler that uses the method for displaying status messages.

```
void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {

      Alert.Show("Your Message");
   }
   catch (Exeception ex )
   {
      Alert.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

**In your Case :**

```
public static class Connection
    {
        public static ArrayList GetCoffeeByType(string coffeetype)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();
                var query = from p in db.tableabc select p;
                list = query.ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Alert.Show(ex.Message);

            }
            return list;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, have some problem! can i put class other than App_Code?

Comment: Yes , you can use this class just like any other classes

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to invoke `MessageBox.Show` in an ASP.NET application. Try this instead:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var script = "alert(" + System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ex.Message, true) + ")";
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", script, true);
}
```

Note that you need to get the `Message` property on the caught exception, `ex`, and you should use [`JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784638%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to safely escape the alert message.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, have some problem! ok so i tried with unsuccessful results Error 8 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(System.Web.UI.Control, System.Type, string, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments